# Flex/Flash runtime error #2063 on android

Tags: android, apache-flex

I am developing a modular Flex (4.1) application. It runs flawlessly on a PC, but as soon as I try to run it on my android tablet (Samsung Galaxy) I immediately get multiple runtime errors.

The errors I am getting are all error code #2063, which seems to decode to "Error attempting to execute IME command.". I don't think my code contains any commands or references to IME in any way. I have googled this extensively but haven't been able to locate an answer. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you trying to build a Native App or a browser based app?  How are you trying to run the app on your tab?  Which Galaxy Tab are you using (7 or 10.1)?

Comment: I am using the 10.1 tab, and I am running a web-based application.