# Uncaught Error #2063 exception in Android flex application

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex

My clients using my application on ANDROID and a lot of them are reporting uncaught exception error while using my Flex 4.6 application with latest Flash Player 11.1 swc.

My Flex application uses standard SPARK and MX components. The uncaught exception occurs immediately after application is launched, however none of my functions (connecting to RTMP, RTMFP & socket servers) seem to cause it, the error occurs after all the functions that I call upon program start have successfully executed.

Looks like error code #2063 means "Error attempting to execute IME command.".

My code doesn't call or access any IME functions at all.

It seems that this developer is experiencing same issue and is unable to locate the solution or workaround:

[Flex/Flash runtime error #2063 on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248995/flex-flash-runtime-error-2063-on-android)

Also, none of the clients using Windows/Mac/Linux are experiencing this issue, only Android clients.

And they all are accessing same application/same code/exact same file.

It also seems like clients are not doing anything specific that triggers this error - they just start my flash site on their android browser and do not do any interaction with it, and getting this error just after launch.

What do I do / what is the best work around for this issue?

And I obviously don't have a stack trace, because my users are using it DO NOT use Adobe Flash Player debugger, however this person and posts seem to be exactly same issue and they have stack trace: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3410527

I have also submitted this issue to Adobe BugBase: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3101786.

Thanks

Comment: Same error for my app flash app on android. +1 to question

Answer (score 0):

can you add to your code the `UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR` listener on the main movie loaderInfo object? If you can then it should intercept this error and you can collect some information about it or just ignore it if it doesn't break your application.

best regards